# How to return the output of stored procedure into a string variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I want to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server and assign the output to a string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Check_User_Password
    @name NVARCHAR(30),
    @email NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @pass NVARCHAR(50)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT dbo.Mitarbeiter.Name, dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email 
              FROM dbo.Mitarbeiter
              WHERE dbo.Mitarbeiter.Name = @name 
                AND dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email = @email
    BEGIN
        SET @pass = dbo.Mitarbeiter.Password
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @pass = null
    END

    RETURN @pass
END
```

I have changed what I wrote wrong

Comment: Why not use `FUNCTION`?

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  `@Exists` is not defined, for instance.  `SET @pass = dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email` makes no sense.  The name starts with `sp_`, which is highly discouraged.

Comment: Consider an `OUTPUT` parameter or a scalar valued function.

Comment: what gordon said, and also you can initialize the variable to null to start with instead of the else logic like this: DECLARE @pass nvarchar(50)= null

Comment: that is from translator, German-English

I have made mistakes when writing on forum, I actually need if user forgot password, he must enter email and username, if found, he gets on his email password, so I need string value

Comment: aber code Teil:

set @pass = dbo.Mitarbeiter.Password

funktioniert nicht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on below sample, just add your stuff and it will work

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE return_string 
        (@param1 NVARCHAR(10),
        @param2 NVARCHAR(10), 
        @output NVARCHAR(10) OUT)
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF (1=1)
            SET @output = 'here'
        else
            SET @output = null
    END
```

to test

```
    declare @out nvarchar(10)
    exec return_string 'firdt param', 'second param', @out out
    select @out
```

I hope this will help you achive what you need.

So your SP would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Check_User_Password
(
    @name nvarchar(30),
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @pass nvarchar(50) OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM dbo.Mitarbeiter
                WHERE dbo.Mitarbeiter.Name = @name 
                    and dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email = @email)
    BEGIN
        SET @pass = (SELECT dbo.Mitarbeiter.Name
                        FROM dbo.Mitarbeiter
                        WHERE dbo.Mitarbeiter.Name = @name 
                            and dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email = @email)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @pass = null
    END
END
```

Comment: the code works, i just changed a part,

and works fine

Dankeschön

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Check_User_Password
@name nvarchar(30),
@email nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @pass nvarchar(50) = null

IF EXISTS(SELECT dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email FROM dbo.Mitarbeiter
            WHERE dbo.Mitarbeiter.Name = @name and dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email = @email)
BEGIN
    SELECT @pass = dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email FROM dbo.Mitarbeiter
    WHERE dbo.Mitarbeiter.Name = @name and dbo.Mitarbeiter.Email = @email
END
  PRINT @pass
END
```

Comment: Here I always get value 0